# Categories and subcategories with seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form and want to be able to select category & subcategory.

This is an automatic example from seeds.rb:

```
Examples:

cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)
```

There is cities.first - but can you do it for cities.sixth or cities.twelfth...?
Is there a different way to do it and connect subcategories with categories in the file?

Comment: Are you aware that `cities.first` is just a different way to say `cities[0]`?

Comment: Canonically Chicago is the 2nd city.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally advise against using positions to assign subcategories.  The possibility exists that there is data on another devs machine or a server.

I generally do it something like:

```
city = City.find_or_create_by_name(
name: "Chicago"
)

mayor = Mayor.find_or_create_by_city_id(
city_id: city.id,
name: 'Emanuel')
```